# GVIM question for search and replacing text

Tags: regex, vim

we're looking to search and replace some text using GVIM.
We have to identify any " that is not preceeded AND proceeded by a comma (forgetting the ones at the beginning and end of the line).
Then replace those with '

In terms of identiying the search string, we've got that cracked with:

```
/[^,]"[^,]
```

And in terms of replacing the text with the correction, we have got as far as:

```
:.,$s/[^,]”[^,]/’/gc
```

BUT

this seems to be deleting 3 characters i.e.

```
,"SHELL 1" DIAMETER","help"
,SHELL 'DIAMETER help,"help"
```

What we need is something that will make:

```
,"SHELL 1' DIAMETER","help
```

into

```
,SHELL 1'", help
```

Comment: did you mean to remove ` DIAMETER` from the final example?

Answer (score 2):

you just need to define the start and end of you match with `\zs` and `\ze`

```
/[^,]\zs"\ze[^,]
```

also if you have already defined your search term using `/` you can leave the search portion of the search replace empty and it will use the current search.

```
:.,$s//’/gc
```

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the check mark under the arrows :)